# SQL, Faster way to execute than where and?

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I'm new to SQL and I'm looking for a faster way to execute a quite simple statement. There are multiple values in a table which should match to return the rows. Is there a faster way to proceed through? The table is a view where I don't have admin rights to make any changes.

```
select * from TABLE.View_xy 
where location=1 
and b=2
and c=3
and d=4
and e=5
and f=6
and manDate between (TIMESTAMP '2016-06-01 00:00:00') and (TIMESTAMP '2016-06-02 23:59:59') 
and g=7
```

Comment: That's the fastest way, just create an index on the = predicates, and end it with the between one.

Comment: @Gar though they don't have permissions probably and it is a view not a table.

Comment: putting indexes on the equivalent underlying fields would help, unless some of those fields are derivative/calculated values.

Comment: Are you experiencing a problem with that query ? Is it running long? hanging? etc. ?  At a glance, it appears just fine as is, but it may depend greatly what the actual SQL in the view looks like. If it's not coming back in a timely fashion, include more information on the data size/info, as well as an explain.  That would help spot any potential bottlenecks.

Comment: I'm trying to improve the speed of a very big VBA Macro which takes 1 hour to execute. There are is lot of data processed with multiple sql statements... this is just the first :)

Comment: Maybe instead of focussing on single queries, look at the "big picture": is this query *with the same parameters* executed multiple times? If so, you could remember and re-use the results.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if its a view and you can't adjust it, there's not much you can do with this query to make it more efficient(every think is just basic filter conditions).

What I can suggest is this:

Create a temp table containing the view's data, index this table and then run the select on the table. You can do this as many times as you need.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_for_select AS
SELECT * FROM TABLE.View_xy;

CREATE INDEX IND_NAME ON tmp_for_select(location,b,c,d,e,f,g,manDate) ;

select * from tmp_for_select
where location=1 and b=2 and c=3
  and d=4 and e=5 and f=6
  and manDate between (TIMESTAMP '2016-06-01 00:00:00') and (TIMESTAMP '2016-06-02 23:59:59') 
  and g=7;

DROP TABLE tmp_for_select;
```

Comment: "insufficient privileges" :)

Comment: You can't even create a different table?

Comment: ORA-01031 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges. :'(